# How to program in Scala to be forward-compatible with Dotty

Tags: scala, dotty

In hist recent [talk](http://www.infoq.com/presentations/data-types-issues) at Strange Loop Martin Odersky shed the light on his vision of Scala's future version called Dotty. I understand this is work-in-progress and it even may not flow into Scala (at least not very fast) due to many possible backward-compatibility issues. But if it happens, how should we program in Scala today to be forward-compatible with Dotty? I didn't get all the ideas from the talk so I'd like someone more profound to summarize the changes and describe how can we prepare to them.

Answer (score 36):

The only other advice I would give is to also stay away from structural types containing a type members. Those type members are the elements that make type-checking in Scala turing complete, and I am not yet sure whether we want to support that in Dotty. Structural types that contain only vals and defs will likely stay supported.

Comment: Martin, do libraries heavily relying on higher-kinded types, like Scalaz, ought to be rewritten in alternative style? As I understand there will be no backward binary compatibility and code compiled with pre-Dotty Scala version won't work with Dotty, am I right?

Comment: It's too early to tell. We will maintain some backwards compatibility with higher-kinded types as long as it requires not more than reasonable effort.

Comment: Are these answers still relevant today?

Answer (score 11):

Towards the end of the talk, he says `"if your program is compiled without any language feature imports for higher-kinded and existentials then you should be ok"`.

So if I understand it correctly the only thing you would need to be aware of is any possible usage of existential types or higher-kinded types in your code.